# How do I extract specific links using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

This is my current code:

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")

for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

I want to only extract links that contain "instagram" on the specific page that I am scraping.

The link is usually going to be something like this:

https://www.instagram.com/(username/

I want to only scrape this and print it on the console. How would I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked out the `in` operator in a context other than the `for` statement? Might be exactly what you need. Just like you can look for a `link` in `links`, you can look for a `substring` in a `string`.

Comment: I'm very new to coding just started the other day, I was wondering how exactly would I structure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@href]')

for link in links:
    href = link.get_attribute('href')
    if 'instagram' in href:
        print(href)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work too. XPath with a specific predicate :

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"instagram")]')

for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```